# How to use a randomly generated unique number as primary key in Spring Boot and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot application with MySQL database. I have the following requirement-
I want to use randomly generated unique number (like 125665585) as primary key instead of **SEQUENCE/AUTO/TABLE/IDENTITY**. I came accross the UUID, but don't want to use it and keep the primary key as a primitive data type only.
Can anybody please explain how it should be done in Spring Boot and whether JPA/Hibernate has any pre-existing feature for this?

Comment: Don't. Use a UUID if you must else let the database handle it. There is no garantueed random number generator and when scaling this will inevitably lead to issues. If you want something other then a UUID you could look at twitter Snowflake to generate ids. But in general you should stick with DB generated ids.

Comment: your requirements of "random" and "unique" could outweigh each other - random numbers are usually not supposed to be unique.

Comment: You can use `System.nanoTime();`